# How to modify the function $y=a-be^{-cx}$ so that it will look wavy? [ other forms can be suggested ]

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions, curves, upper-lower-bounds, wave-equation

I need to modify the equation of the curve $y=a-be^{-cx}$ so that it looks wavy (using sine function), where the amplitude decreases as $x$ increases, and it has an upper bound.

To illustrate this, I just draw how it looks, so excuse me for the imperfect drawing;

[image]

I tried to replace $x$ with $sin(x)$, that is, $y=a-be^{-c \sin(x)}$, but did not work.

Also, I tried to add one more constant $d$, so the equation is $y=a-be^{-c \sin(dx)}$ still did not work.

It is okay for me to have any form other than $y=a-be^{-cx}$ as long as the curve will look as illustrated above. One more restriction is that the curve must have finitely many terms, so I can not use series such as Fourier series.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $y=a-(2+\sin x)be^{-cx}$ will work. The $2$ can be changed to any number $\ge1$ and the limiting value will still be an upper bound for the function; if it's changed to exactly $1$, the upper bound will be attained over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. That is exactly what I was looking for.